# How do i find all the prime numbers in a certain range and print them out?

Tags: python, iteration

I want to list all the prime numbers between 100 to 200 line by line...
This is the code i have tried to write. I am trying to use a for-loop to see if the number(eg.100) is divisible by any number from 2 to the number itself. So i want the program to check if it is divisible by any one of the c values and if it is then just stop the program and then continue to the next number(eg.101, 102...) but i cant seem to find a way to do that idk how to properly use the break command

```
prime = False
for i in range(100, 201):
    for c in range(2, i):
        if i % c == 0:
            prime = False
            break
        else:
            prime =True
    if prime == True:
        print(i)
```

Comment: You have almost everything right except you need to reset the value of `prime` to `False` for every element in the list. Also, you can't make it to `True` if it is not just divisible by one element, it has to be not divisible by all.

Comment: You initialise `prime`to `False` so no need to set it again, only set `True` if you get that far. Change the indedntation of the final `if` so it's not within the `for`loop - that has to run once it's finished. Also, you only need to check a number up to `num/2` to save a bit of comp time :)

Comment: Just a sidenote, it's enough to test whether a number `n` is divisible up to `sqrt(n)` inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

first you need install sympy with pip

```
pip install sympy
```

then use this code example

```
from sympy import isprime

start_range = 10
stop_range = 100
primes = []

for n in range(start_range , stop_range + 1):
    if isprime(n):
        primes.append(n)

print(primes)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
for i in range(100, 201):
    prime =True
    for c in range(2, i):
        if i % c == 0:
            prime = False
            break
       
    if prime == True:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think of the situation as: when we start testing a particular number for primacy, we assume it is prime. If we find a divisor, we know it's not prime, and mark it appropriately. If we reach the end of the candidate divisors, and we haven't marked it as non-prime yet, then it is prime.

A few other points to consider:

1. There's not much point in testing whether even numbers (other than 2) are prime. They're not, so we might as well not test whether they are.
2. Likewise, when we're generating candidate divisors, there's no real point in generating even numbers. An even number can't divide evenly into an odd number.
3. Divisors come in pairs. For every divisor *greater* than the square root of a number, there must be a matching one that's *less* than the square root. If we don't find a divisor less than or equal to the square root, we won't find one greater than the square root either (or, wording it more directly: if we don't find a divisor less than or equal to the square root of the number, we can stop looking--it's prime).

Changing the subject a bit: when you're looking for all the primes up to some limit, you might want to consider using the sieve of Eratosthenes instead.